# Latex Tabular - adding more columns using \quad

Tags: tables

I am new to using latex. I am trying to add two more columns using `\quad` and `\multicoulmn` to the below latex code. I tried to add another `\quad`  and use `\qquad` but it didn't work.

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Summary of the IoT\_BOT and ToN\_IoT Datasets}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r@{\quad}rl}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rule{0pt}{12pt}Dataset}&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{No. Features}\\[2pt]
\hline\rule{0pt}{12pt}{12pt}
IoT\_Botnet  &    29 & \\
Ton\_IoT IoT\_Fridge  &   6 &\\[2pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I want the table to look like this.
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a sketch of the expected output to your question. Where do you want to add a column? What's the expected alignment of contents in this column? What do you want to use `\multicolumn` for in this context?

Comment: Neither `\quad` nor `\qquad` can be used to add a new column. The use of `@{\quad}` in the code in your question influences the horizontal white space between the first and the second column. It does not ann another column.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just updated the post to include a sketch.

Comment: The instruction `\begin{tabular}{r@{\quad}rl}` tells LaTeX that the table is supposed to have three columns: the first two have type `r`, the third and last has type `l`. Note that `@{\quad}` does *not* define a column type; instead, it tells LaTeX *how much whitespace* to insert between columns 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

The following should get you started. Filling in the texts and numbers according to your screenshot is left as an exercise to the reader.

I used the `caption` package for improved spacing between caption and table, as well as the `booktabs` package for horizontal lines with improved spacing. To be able to use 4 left aligned column types in the table, I used `\begin{tabular}{llll}`. (The 4 `l` represent 4 left aligned columns.) I also replaced the `center` environment with the `\centering` command since the former adds additional vertical white space around the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Summary of the IoT\_BOT and ToN\_IoT Datasets}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
Dataset               & No.  Features & No. Records & Traffic Type  \\
\midrule
IoT\_Botnet           & 29            & 1           & text          \\
Ton\_IoT IoT\_Fridge  &  6            & 2           & text          \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I make a horizontal white space between columns?

Comment: There already is a horizontal white space between each pair of columns. You could increase it by changing the value of `\tabcolsep`, for example by adding `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt}` or any other value of your choice. (The default value is 6pt) If you add this command to the preamble, you will change all tables in your document, if you add it inside of a `table` environment, you will just change this particular table. However, please be aware, that increasing the white space between columns does not necessarily increase the readability of the tables.

Comment: It worked! I appreciate your help.